# Can I promote a many-to-many relationship to an entity without changing all references to the existing navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a many-to-many relationship between Questions and Answers. But now I want to add a cost to a valid question and answer pair. I was trying to think of a way of doing it that would avoid having to change all references to the original property. Is it possible?

```
   public class Question
    {
       public int ID { get; set:}
       public string Text { get; set; }

       //The original many-to-many
       //public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers  { get; set; }

       //but now I need a QuestionAnswerPair as an entity
       //problem is that Adding or Removing does not affect the QuestionAnswerPairs collection
       [NotMapped]
       public ICollection<Answer> Answers
       {
            get
            {
                return QuestionAnswerPairs.Select(x => x.Answer).ToList();
            }
       }

        public virtual ICollection<QuestionAnswerPair> QuestionAnswerPairs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public int ID {get; set;}            
        public string Text { get; set; }

        //The original many-to-many
        //public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    }

    //UnitCosts should only be added to valid Question-Answer pairs
    //so I want to have a cost linked to the many-to-many relationship
    public class QuestionAnswerPair
    {
        public int ID {get; set;}

        public int AnswerID { get; set; }

        public virtual Answer Answer { get; set; }

        public int QuestionID { get; set; }

        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

        public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will soon find out that this is not possible when you want to use the navigation property in LINQ-to-entities queries.

If you'd do something like

```
context.Questions.SelectMany(q => q.Answers)
```

EF will throw an exception that `Answers` is not supported (*Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported*).

If you want to work around this by adding `AsEnumerable`:

```
context.Questions.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(q => q.Answers)
```

you will find out that for each question queries are executed to load their `QuestionAnswerPairs` collections and the `Answer`s. (If lazy loading is enabled). And if you want to prevent *that*, you've got to fetch questions with `Incude` statements.

You really can't do anything better but include the `QuestionAnswerPairs` in your LINQ queries.

That's why it's always a big decision to implement many-to-many associations with transparent junction tables (i.e. no junction classes). Sooner or later users will want to add descriptive data to junction records. Pure junction tables are very rare in real-life applications.